# How can I call 'Swash'/'Stylistic Set' Characters from an OpenType font in HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, css, fonts, opentype

I'm working on a project right now that within the OpenType font has several variations of the same character. All the characters have the same Unicode ID but have different GID numbers and some other reference like Swash or Stylistic SetXX (ss01) (found this information in indesign). Is there any way to use these characters in an HTML document?

Example: J (normal), J (with speed blur), J (made out of chains), All have unicode id: 004A, but have GID values of 43, 206 and 233 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

font-variant-alternates is what you want: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-variant-alternates-prop

I don't know how widely supported it is yet, and bet that it's not in IE.

This page shows support for OTF in general: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf ; It is not clear whether complete support is really complete, in this sense.

Demos of Firefox and IE support: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/opentype/opentype-fontfont/index.html

Comment: "Don't cite this document other than as work in progress." - W3C

Comment: @Alerty: What's your point? Are you aware that actual browsers that actual people use already support much of CSS3 and HTML5, even though those standards are works in progress.

Comment: Only wanted to state the fact that the font features are not widely implemented yet.

Comment: @Alerty: Thanks, you may note that I mentioned that in the second of my two lines.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for however it appears to be unsupported in any browser (At least I couldn't get it to work [Did anyone else try?]). Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @AdeptOfHermes: Check this: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/opentype/opentype-fontfont/index.html

Answer (score 9):

I hadn’t heard of [`font-variant-alternates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750790/20578), but I do know that [Firefox 4 and above support `-moz-font-feature-settings`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-moz-font-feature-settings), which lets you apply OpenType features via CSS.

Example code from a [Mozilla Hacks blog post on `moz-font-feature-settings`](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/11/firefox-4-font-feature-support/):

```css
.altstyles {
    /* format: feature-tag=[0,1] with 0 to disable, 1 to enable */
    /* dlig = discretionary ligatures, ss01 = stylistic set 1 */
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "dlig=1,ss01=1";
}
```

As far as I know, no other browser supports a similar feature yet.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, the project I am working on only supports -webkit. Support for font-variant-alternates doesn't appear to be in high demand. I hardly found any people talking about it.

Comment: @AdeptOfHermes: ah, sure. It’s a shame WebKit hasn’t got any equivalent yet. You’d think that with `@font-face` being used more, there’d be more call for this sort of thing.